# Can I use a notebook wireless card in a different device?

Tags: wireless-networking

I had a netbook recently given to me, it was old and not working. I took it apart, to see if I could fix it, and the wiring had become frayed and completely loose on some things. Pretty much irreparable, at least with my skill set.

Anyways, I took it apart and wanted to use a couple things for parts. I was wondering, am I able to take the wireless card out and use it for something else? For example, could I somehow turn it into a USB wireless card? I've been searching on the internet, but haven't really come across anything talking about it.

Any information is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give more information? What brand is the notebook? and name of the wirelles card? You can use your card to the hardware with a similar structure.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit tricky. There's really three kinds of wireless adaptors for laptops floating around. Older laptops would use a mini pci adaptor and newer ones would use mini pci-e adaptors. Either of these should have adaptors that will convert them into a internal card for the non mini version of its form factor. My answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/500012/10165) goes into the details of that

Some netbooks also use USB for wireless - from a random sampling they apparently have six pins - the usual 4 pin USB, one for the wireless LED and one for the switch. You might be able to grab the USB cable off something like a mouse, solder those in, and add a led or switch. It would need some pretty epic scrounging and/or soldering skills tho. You're unlikely to be able to convert a mini pci/pci-e into a USB adaptor

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on the device itself right? If it's connected through a standard port, or if a port converter exist for it, then it should be possible, electronically that is. The other side of the track is how it's antenna was built, if it's built into the device itself, great. If it turns out to utilize a huge antenna inside the screen, then you'll need to somehow replace it too.

EDIT : There's also the problem of WPA2 standard. Old wireless adapter only support WEP, so it's use could be limited to open wifi network or where WPA compatibility is still supported.